# Segmentation fault: 11; (xcode 8, Swift 3) after using NotificationCenter

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, notificationcenter

### Getting Segmentation fault in Xcode 8

I have recently migrated my project to **Swift 3**. Xcode Version **8.0** (8A218a)
I get this error whenever I use UIKeyboardWillShow notification :

> Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11`

This is how I am using the notification in my code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myViewController.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myViewController.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name:NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

}


func keyboardWillShow(_ sender: Notification) {
     //keyboardWillShow Method
}

func keyboardWillHide(_ sender: Notification) {
    // keyboardWillHide Method
}
```

Project runs successfully when I comment out the code in viewWillAppear method.

Answer (score 5):

The main topic: ***Segmentation fault: 11***, it's a bug of Xcode8/Swift3 and you should send a [bug report](http://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).

And about your code:

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow)
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide)
```

There are no methods removing observers specifying only their names. You need to specify observer object for `removeObserver(_:)`.

I'm not sure this is what you intend, but you can use `removeObserver(_:name:object:)` method like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

I'm sure this would not crash your Xcode.

Comment: BTW if you're targeting at OS X 10.11 / iOS 9.0 or later, you may not need to add `NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver` anymore. Ref: [Foundation Release Notes for OS X v10.11 and iOS 9](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-Foundation/index.html)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Could you please inform, whether this issue exists in Xcode 8.1 and accompanying Swift-3 and Foundation framework?

Comment: @MottiShneor, as far as I tested, Xcode 8.1 (8B62) does not crash with the same code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in the same conditions and environment (Swift 3, Xcode 8) and to resolve this problem you should put:

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

instead of:

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow)
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide)
```